# Legal Term for Signing A Document That is Believed To Be Untrue

Tags: contract-law, common-law, definition

Is there a term in Law for when someone signs a document as true when said individual is under the belief that the contents of the document are untrue?

For example, if I was asked to sign a document that says "the sky is green", and I saw the sky that morning and it was blue. Signing this document would amount to (insert term here).

Answer (score 1):

If you are under oath it is called [perjury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perjury). If you are not under oath it is called lying.

Comment: Note that for this to be perjury, the false claim would have to be material.  It's hard to imagine a case in which the color of the sky would be material.

Comment: So, is someone signing a document or contract under oath?

Comment: Generally, no. An affidavit or statutory declaration is made under oath.

Comment: You can only perjure yourself when under oath or attesting before the court.  If you're not in that scenario, it's probably "false witness" that the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Signing this document would amount to **free speech**.

There are circumstances, as comments have said, where we are not allowed to lie. But these circumstances are circumscribed - such as speech under penalty of perjury, attesting to facts under a regulatory rule (signing certain financial documents), etc. Of course, lies about facially mundane things like your address or how long you've lived a place are fraudulent if circumstances align.